# Disable AVPlayer dropdown on tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I want to add my own custom dropdown when a video is playing and the user swipes down. However, the default dropdown with asset info and audio settings always shows first when I swipe. I know I can get rid of it by making the video not be fullscreen, but then I would lose playback controls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Update**

```
    let swipeDownGR = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipes(sender:)))
    swipeDownGR.direction = .down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDownGR)
```

The default dropdown usually captures the gesture before my recognizer does.

Comment: Are you using AVPlayerController?

Comment: yes, and I'm handling the gesture as seen in the updated question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if you can get rid of some of the default behaviors that AVPlayerController provides. I actually would recommend creating your own custom playback controls (which isn't actually as hard as it sounds). All you have to do is to create a translucent UIView and overlay it on top of the AVPlayer, and add the elements that you want which gives you full control over the controls/elements that are there when the video is paused.

Comment: If I did that though, wouldn't I lose the nice progress bar with scanning and all the nice built in controls?

Comment: Yeah I had to make a tvos app with certain requirements that AVPlayerController couldn't satisfy before, so I created my own custom controls which was a lot easier than I thought, probably just took me an afternoon so if you can't find a way around the default dropdown you can definitely take this approach.

Comment: Hmm, well thanks for your help, but we need default controls and making it function exactly like the default player won't be quick and easy.

Comment: Do you maybe have some sample code somewhere of how you built your custom progress bar?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't it was part of company code that I wrote. It was simply an overlay on top of the AVPlayer that would go transparent if the player was playing, and would show up with a translucent background color. The time indicator of the video was a simple rectangle with a circle overlayed on top that gets updated every 1/30 second depending on the video's current playtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc: AVPlayerViewController = ... //your view controller
vc.playbackControlsIncludeInfoViews = false
```